# scrolling CoreText in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, core-text

I am experimenting with CoreText, one of the problems i have is that content isn't scrollable and idk how to make it scrollable... with labels this code works:

```
//Calculate the expected size based on the font and linebreak mode of your label
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(300,9999);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [labelText sizeWithFont:label.font
                                  constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                      lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];

//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = label.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
label.frame = newFrame;
```

my test project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47384598/AA_CoreText.zip

but what should i do with CoreText? Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: you may create a new subview to draw on it , and add the subview to CTView 

then you can scroll it

Answer (score 1):

You should probably render your CoreText frames into a `UIView`. Then, add this `UIView` to your `UIScrollView` as a subview and set the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView` such that the `contentSize` is large enough to fit your UIView holding the CoreText.

Note that if the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView` is less than the size of the view on the screen, it will not need to scroll.